# Disabling All Form Elements In Selected Div (edited)

Tags: javascript

I have one large form that is separated into different sections with divs. Each section is within the same form (bigform) and I need to make sure only one section is enabled/editable at a time. And if the user changes sections after entering data into one section, all data would be cleared from the old section before disabling it. The ideal way for me is to have something like this:

```
<form>
    <select name="selector">
        <option>Choose Which Div To Enable</option>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
        <option value='3'>Three</option>
    </select>
</form>


<form name="bigform">
    <div id="1">
        <input type="text">
        <select name="foo">
            <option>bar</option>
            <option>bar</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="2">
        <input type="text">
        <select name="foo">
            <option>bar</option>
            <option>bar</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="3">
        <input type="text">
        <select name="foo">
            <option>bar</option>
            <option>bar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

When the user selects option "Two" in the selector form, all form elements in DIVs 1 and 3 would be disabled. I've searched the web for hours but I cannot find a solution. What's the best method to achieve this?

I found this code online that does "almost" what I want but not quite. It 'toggles' the form elements in the given element (el). What I'm trying to do is sort of the opposite of this.

```
    <form>
        <select name="selector" onChange="toggleDisabled(document.getElementByID(this.value))>
            <option>Choose Which Div To Enable</option>
            <option value='1'>One</option>
            <option value='2'>Two</option>
            <option value='3'>Three</option>
        </select>
    </form>
<script>
function toggleDisabled(el){
    try {
        el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
    }
    catch(E){}

    if (el.childNodes && el.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < el.childNodes.length; x++) {
            toggleDisabled(el.childNodes[x]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't realy understand.. do you want to Disable All Element in the selected Div?

Comment: I've edited the form to make it more clear that I'm NOT looking prevent some input elements from being submitted but to make only one section at a time availabe to the user.

Comment: you mean if he finish filling and selecting on Div1 it will be disabled and Div2 will be enabled..and etc?

Comment: please take a look. I've tried to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to solve it *without* using a scripting library such as jQuery:

```
function disableFormFields(container, isDisabled) {
  var tagNames = ["INPUT", "SELECT", "TEXTAREA"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tagNames.length; i++) {
    var elems = container.getElementsByTagName(tagNames[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++) {
      elems[j].disabled = isDisabled;
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
<select name="selector" onchange="partiallyDisableForm(this)">
  <!-- give every option a numeric value! -->
  <option value='0'>Choose Which Div To Enable</option>
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
```

---

```
function partiallyDisableForm(selector) {
  // don't forget to give your form the ID "bigform"
  var form = document.getElementById("bigform");
  var parts = form.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var part = parts[i];
    // give your form parts the ID "formpart_1" through "formpart_3"
    if (part.id.match(/^formpart_\d+$/)) {
      // you must implement what to do if selector.value is 0
      var isDisabled = (part.id != "formpart_" + selector.value);
      disableFormFields(part, isDisabled);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. Just one more thing: how to disable all the sections on page load?

Comment: You could just have them disabled right from the start in the HTML. Or you could make option "0" the default (selected) one, and use `<body onload="partiallyDisableForm(document.getElementById('selector'))">` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

> When the user selects option "Two" in the selector form, all form elements in DIVs 1 and 3 would be disabled. So when user submits "bigform", only the values inside div 2 would be submitted.

No. the form will always be submitted as a whole, regardless of what elements were disabled in UI.

If you want to submit only one set of form items, create a separate form for each set.

Comment: Yes, but the values would be POST value of the disabled elements would be inaccessible once submitted or will be overridden.

Comment: Disabled inputs are NOT submitted with the rest of the form. This has always been my experience. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to prevent some input elements from submittng, and it might be safer/easier to do the selective saving on the server side, as it would stop erroneous results being saved if JS broke/was compromised.

You could disable the elements not being submitted and maybe change their name attributes to ensure the values weren't used by the server.

You could also assign a name/value to a submit button, and parse this on the server-side. It would be trivial to use Javascript to set a value n the submit button to tell the server side to only the the required buttons.

Answer (score 0):

So you have N sections with id's 1..N, and you want only section i to be active?

If you put it in that wording, I would code it somewhat like this - mind: my jQuery is not that strong, I'm merely pseudo-jQuerying:

```
function enable( element, sensitive ) {
   //recursively disable this node and it's children       
   element.disabled = !sensitive;
   if( element.childNodes ) {
      for( var i = 0; i != element.childNodes.length; ++i ) {          
       enable( element.childNodes[i], sensitive );
      }
   }
}

// this function should rely on the structure of your document
// it ought to visit all sections that need to be enabled/disabled
function enableSection( i ) {
   $("#bigform > div").each( function( index, element ) {
       enable( element, index==i );
   });
}

$("#sectionselector").change( function( ) {
   // find value of active section
   var activesection = $("#sectionselector").value; // or the like
   enableSection( activesection );
} );
```

Comment: I think you understood correctly what I'm trying to do. Let me try this out. although I wish I didn't have to include jquery just for this task.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to work. Wouldn't all the sections have to be disabled first? I don't see how this script even knows which div contains all the sections. Could you please explain?

Comment: @xtofl: You silently assume that jQuery is present. There is no indication for that.