# Cannot disable Twitter bootstrap button with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing some AJAX when a button is clicked

```
            $btn.button('loading');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: 'event/',
                data: put_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.redirect) {
                        window.location = data.redirect;
                    }
                    else {
                        $btn.button('reset');

                        if ($btn.is('#my-btn')) {
                            console.log('disabling button');
                            $btn.prop('disabled', true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

`disabling button` shows up in the console, but the button does not get disabled. Loading and resetting the button works just fine. I tried `.addClass('disabled')` and `.attr('disabled','disabled')`, but those also don't work.

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wvbeeg

Comment: When you look at the DOM structure, does the button have the "disabled" property? Or is that not being set either?

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: You might also look here for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery

Comment: @KivakWolf it flashes the disabled attribute for a split second then disappears. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wvbeeg

Comment: @charlietfl see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wvbeeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `button('reset')` is asynchronous. You can watch the changes live in the html an see they aren't immediate

A short delay after reset resolves the problem, but personallly i would just code this whole process myself instead of using the bootstrap API

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mybutton').click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function() {/// mimic ajax delay
      $btn.button('reset');
      setTimeout(function() {//  short delay after reset
        $btn.prop('disabled', true);

      }, 200);

    }, 1000);

  });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbJraX)**</kbd>

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to rely on a timeout of an ambiguous number of 200 milliseconds? Wouldn't that leave you open to potential problems if the computer is under load?

Comment: @KivakWolf yes that's why I suggested getting completely away from using bootstrap button API.

Answer (score -1):

Remove:

```
$btn.button('reset');
```

For some reason, this doesn't evaluate until after you disable it. (It's asynchronous)

Rather than resetting the button using the 'reset' code, it might be better to just remove the `disabled` property if it exists. That will effectively enable the button if it should be active.

Modified code:

```
        $btn.button('loading');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'event/',
            data: put_data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if (data.redirect) {
                    window.location = data.redirect;
                }
                else {
                    if ($btn.is('#my-btn')) {
                        console.log('disabling button');
                        $btn.prop('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        $btn.prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Bonus tip: Don't use .removeProp() to re-enable the button. That will completely remove the property and you won't be able to use it again. More about prop() here: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are using jQuery to bind a click event to the button. So the disable property won't be able to stop it. In your code you will need to add this:

```
 $('#mybutton').off('click');
```

That will unbind the event from the button.