# Photos Displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I disable the submit button once the photos is displayed on the page? Anyone knows?
Here's my code:

```
        if("#pic" == true){
         }
         else{
           $("#submit").click(function () {           
           var button = $(this);
           button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');           
          });

        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery

Comment: the submit button need to disabled when the photo is displayed

Comment: Do you have some sort of variable keeping track of whether the photo is displayed or not?

Comment: Just to let you know you're missing a closing bracket for the first if statement.  if("#pic" == true){ //if block }else{ //else block }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable button in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

here's the modified code

```js
$('#pic').on('load', function() {
  console.log("loaded");
  
  $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="pic" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />

<button id="submit">hello</button>
```

if the img source is improper it won't render and the load method is hence not called, so we are sure of the proper image source and after rendering it calls the `Load` method in which you can disable your button

Comment: If I want to display 5 photos that the user uploaded how should I write the source load method?

Comment: the photos are in the loop `$("#photo" + i)`

Comment: pls share entire snippet of upload + html