# Disable just one button out of set buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've coded table creation PHP which create a table using data from a mysql table called job_list. Each row of the table have a button which is used by the user to select the job.

My problem is here I want to disable just one button out of all the buttons. I tried using a single class which disabled all of them. Then I came across another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery) which is what I want but the problem is, every time I've to click twice for the first time when I click the button in order for the code to work. After the initial click code starts to work as intended.

This is my PHP + HTML code

```
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table">

                <div class="row header">
                    <div class="cell topLeft">
                        Customer Name
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Target
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        File Type
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Job Comment
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Cust. ID
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell topRight">
                        Select Job
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php while ($getJobsRow = $getJobs -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
                    <?php $loopCount++; //Count the loop run through time ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell left <?php if ($numOfRows == $loopCount){ ?>bottomLeft<?php } //Set the CSS class if the loop is at the last row ?> " data-title="Full Name">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['customer_name']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Age">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['Mal_Name']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Job Title">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['FileExt']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['Job_Comment']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Location">
                        <?php echo $getJobsRow['customer_id']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell right <?php if ($numOfRows == $loopCount){ ?>bottomRight<?php } ?> " data-title="Location">
                        <button id="selBtnId_<?php echo $getJobsRow['jId']; ?>" class="selJobBtn w3-btn w3-blue-dark w3-round-medium w3-ripple" data-jid="<?php echo $getJobsRow['jId']; ?>">Select</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selJobBtn').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Functions/OpenjobLister_Function.php',
            type: 'get',
            data: {
                'jid':$(this).data('jid'),
                'uid':$('#uId').val()
            },
            dataType:'text',
            complete:function(data){
                if(data.responseText !== "1"){
                    alert("Data not added");
                }else{
                    disableSelBtn();
                }
            }
        });            
    });
});

function disableSelBtn() {
    const $selBtns = $("button[id*='selBtnId_']");

    $selBtns.on('click', function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    })
}
```

I use the AJAX to send and receive data. I only want to disable the button when the data submission is successful. So can some show me how can I just do it in one click with out having to click twice when using for the first time. If there a better way of doing this please show me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.selJobBtn').on('click', function () {
    var thisButton = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Functions/OpenjobLister_Function.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            'jid':$(this).data('jid'),
            'uid':$('#uId').val()
        },
        dataType:'text',
        complete:function(data){
            if(data.responseText !== "1"){
                alert("Data not added");
            }else{
                $(thisButton).prop('disabled', true);
                //disableSelBtn();
            }
        }
    });            
});
});
```