# Disabled button still responds to click

Tags: jquery-ui

I have made a button disabled by adding class (.addclass) its still disabled but clickable. But if I made that button disabled by adding .attr then its working as expected. How can I make a button disabled and not clickable by using .addclass in jquery

```
$(this._eButton).addClass("disabled");
//this is allowing the button to click even button is disabled
$(this._eButton).attr("disabled", true);
//this works as expected
```

Comment: `addClass` is for CSS ... `attr()` (or `prop()`) is for element attributes (or properties). You may be able to add `pointer-events: none;` to your disabled CSS should then work as you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable button in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery)

Comment: Events worked. Thanks